# What is the conventional way to manage custom property list keys in iPhone applications?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

An [ApplicationName]-Info.plist file is created with every new iPhone SDK project. My question: is it conventional to add custom property keys to Info.plist and access them programmatically or should they be created in a separate plist?

Perhaps it doesn't much matter, but using the bundle descriptor plist for my custom attributes feels dirty.

[Note that I'm not asking about user-facing properties or settings, so I'm not referring to using a Settings bundle plist.]

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of custom property lists are you thinking of?  All I can think of end up being properties that change the behavior of the app, possibly user-facing ones that haven't made it to a settings UI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Info.plist can contain any custom keys. See [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/ConfigFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002091-119027):

> You can include your keys in your
>   bundle’s information property list
>   file if you want all of your keys
>   stored in one place.

I'm doing this for all my projects: I'm using a script to include the svnversion and build date/time in it to identify each build.

I'm using my own namespace (prefixing the keys) to avoid key name clashes.

Comment: Thanks for referencing the doc. I skimmed through and then CMD-F'd for "custom" and came away empty handed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You add them to Info.plist and then access them programmatically.

Using the bundle descriptor plist for your custom attributes isn't dirty, it's almost universal.